# libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

Hi I just installed the AMD propietary driver for my HP pavilion dv6 with switchable graphics with Xubuntu 12.10.

Everything seems to work fine but games doesn't load good and if I use the command:

> LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose fglrxinfo

I get this errors:

```
    libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/gerard/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 (4.2.12173 Compatibility Profile Context 12.10.17))
```

Thanks for your help.

**Edit 1:** Maybe this will help:

```
locate i965_dri.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
```

I don't understand the "-1" in my question I only ask questions as my last alternative.

**Edit 2:** I tried to reinstall the drivers and now i get this error in one of the steps:

```
gerard@gerard-HP-Pavilion-dv6:~$ sudo apt-get -y install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python-keybinder
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/93.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 279 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 184985 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx-updates (from .../fglrx-updates_2%3a12.100.3-0~andrik1_amd64.deb) ...
One or more files have been altered since installation.
Uninstall will not be completed. See /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log for details.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a12.100.3-0~andrik1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle-updates.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle-updates (from .../fglrx-amdcccle-updates_2%3a12.100.3-0~andrik1_amd64.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a12.100.3-0~andrik1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-proces /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: "wrong ELF class" is the key...

Comment: Don't bother with downvotes Gerard Some people just downvote things they do not understand ;)

Comment: I see... Well I'm adding more info about my  issue, any help will be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
I tried to solve it installing `ia32-libs` but i get this errors:

```
 sudo apt-get install ia32-libs Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done ia32-libs is already the newest version. You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: fglrx-amdcccle-updates : Depends: fglrx-updates E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then i tried `apt-get -f install` but still getting cache errors, so I deleted the cache files, then I can install the dependecies but installation failed. The log says that there was missing files in ATI folder so i tried to reinstall it again. Now i used a `force` method using:

`sudo /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh --force`

Finally I could reinstall again using [this method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#WORKAROUND) and now `fglrxinfo`says that everything is correct (i think at least :P):

`display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12171 Compatibility Profile Context 12.10.17`

Thanks Rinzwind for the help !

Comment: I had a similar issue and reinstalling fglrx solved it for me too.